# how to connect 2 computer using socket in tcp/ip?

Tags: python, c#, sockets, python-requests, raspberry-pi

I want to send the data I received from raspberry to an application that I wrote in c# on a computer connected to the same or different network. But I can't connect two computers.

Server Code :

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
take the server name and port name
host = 'local host'
port = 5001
create a socket at server side using TCP / IP protocol
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
bind the socket with server and port number
s.bind(('', port))
allow maximum 1 connection to the socket
s.listen(1)
wait till a client accept connection
c, addr = s.accept()
display client address
print("CONNECTION FROM:", str(addr))
dateTimeObj = str(datetime.now())
print(dateTimeObj)
c.send(dateTimeObj.encode())
disconnect the server
c.close()
```

Client Code :

```
import socket
# take the server name and port name
host = 'local host'
port = 5001
# create a socket at client side using TCP / IP protocol
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# connect it to server and port number on local computer.
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
# receive message string from server, at a time 1024 B
while True:
    msg = s.recv(1024)
    # repeat as long as message
    # string are not empty
    while msg:
        print('Received date :' + msg.decode())
        msg = s.recv(1024)
# disconnect the client
s.close()
```

I have enabled firewall for server code written in python connected to Raspberry pi and allowed for port 4900. I'm leaving a link explaining what I'm doing.
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-ufw/
Then I tried several different ip addresses like "0.0.0.0" , "" , "Pc ip address" , "raspberry ip address"
I write the raspberry ip address in the ip address part in C# and make the port number the same.

My expectation is that just handling the communication can be from python to c# or from python to python. I want to send data from Raspberry to a computer. It can also be considered as 2 different computers.

Comment: Was that a typo?  You've said you allow port 4900, but you're using port 5001.

Comment: *"allow maximum 1 connection to the socket
 - s.listen(1)"* - this is not what listen is doing. It only cares about the number of connections which are not yet accepted

Comment: *"'127.0.0.1'" - this is the local machine, always. You need to specify here the IP address of the servers machine and there you need to bind the server to 0.0.0.0. And make sure that no firewall is blocking traffic

Comment: @SteffenUllrich First of all thanks. So I need to type 127.0.0.1 for host and 0.0.0.0 for bind? I don't quite understand, but I've already tried possible combinations.
      Server ;
      host = 'local host'
      port = 5001
      s.bind(('', port))
      Client ;
      host = 'local host'
      port = 5001
      s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))

Can you tell me exactly where and what to write?

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks Frank Yellin. Yes, I wrote wrong my bad

Comment: The client should connect to the IP address of the server which is reachable from the client. If the server is running on a different system in the same LAN then the LAN-IP of the server as seen from the client need to be used, which is definitely not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I solved the problem by the way, thanks for your help. I want to transfer data from raspberry to windows form application that I wrote in c# on a computer.
Now I have done the communication using raspberry and python on the computer. But when I switch to c# on the computer, I get an error.
The error I get is;
Could not connect because the target machine actively refused

Comment: @OguzhanTelli35: please don't ask new questions in a comment to an existing one. Ask a new question instead with all the details needed to understand and ideally reproduce the problem.